# Why is there no shot noise in conducting wires?

Tags: current, diodes, bjt, noise, electron

Why is there no shot noise in conducting wires, while it is present in junctions and barriers like PN junction? Is electron flow not quantized in wires? If it is, why do a resistor and perfectly conducting wire not produce shot noise? What is the fundamental difference in electron flow in barrier based devices like Bipolar transistor and wire?

Comment: I'm about to go away for the weekend and don't have time to write an answer... but the crux of it is that the coulomb interaction between quasiparticles in a metal is much more important than in a semiconductor, especially if there is an energy scale given by a barrier.  That coulomb interaction smooths out the electron flow and cancels out most or all of the shot noise.

Answer (score 4):

It is not quantized.

You can push an electron in a bit into the cloud of electrons in the wire and a bit of one is pushed out the other end of the wire (when averaged etc.).

You need something like a barrier that will separate discrete electrons to get shot noise.

Of course you do get Johnson-Nyquist noise from the resistance of the wire.

Comment: I beg to differ on the "It is not quantized" statement.  Charge carriers certainly are quantized in a metal, it's just that the fundamental excitation above the ground state is not an electron-hole pair, but a pair of quasiparticles (which may be electron-like, hole-like or neither).

Comment: @JackB 'It' refers to conduction, but your brief physics explanation sounds plausible. Maybe contribute an answer?